# Toggle collapsible content Jquery/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

for a project I have decided to use collapsibles that are in divs controlled by a select menu (aka. a dropdown). So, a user will use the dropdown to select a topic, and based on whichever topic they select, the appropriate div will be shown, which contains a series of collapsible toggles. Each toggle is a question. When the user clicks it, it's content div is either displayed or hidden.

My dropdown is working fine, but it seems the scripts for it and the collapsibles are conflicting, because although the collapsibles work independently, they don't work when added to a div controlled by the dropdown.

Maybe my eyes are tired but I can't seem to spot the problem. Any ideas what the problem is?

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

And the HTML and CSS

```
<div class="op1 box">
         <button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Collapsible1</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Collapsible2</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.content {
        padding: 0 18px;
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

Comment: any reason why you are using a mix of pure js and jQuery?

Comment: At that moment I used it because I thought writing the code would be easier than normal js. But I'm open to a pure JS solution

Comment: Please create a working example which reproduce the issue to make our life easier.

Comment: can you share all of your codes. html seems incomplete